# How to connect XAMPP with Intellij (community version)

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea

I want to connect Intellij idea (community version) to database.I already have XAMPP installed in my windows laptop. Moreover, I installed database navigator in Intellij. Somebody please tell me a way to connect Intellij with MysqL which I have in XAMPP